# How to add list of words inside particular regex

Tags: python-3.x

```
import re
pg_content = "Hello my Ref No: 9XD123D and his Buyer's Ref: 87CVX61"
ref_no = re.findall(r"(?:(?<=Buyer's Ref: )|(?<=Ref No: )|(?<=Ref No : ))[\w\d-]+",pg_content)
print(ref_no)
```

I want to run the script by adding list = ["Buyer's Ref:","Ref No:","Ref No :"] instead of adding "|" to the re.findall line. Is there any solution. Just need to insert all items in the list to re.findall

Comment: What is the expected output here?

Comment: 9XD123D,87CVX61= Output. But I need to use list instead of putting "|"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `re.findall` we can try:

```py
pg_content = "Hello my Ref No: 9XD123D and his Buyer's Ref: 87CVX61 and another Ref No : ABC123"
terms = ["Ref No ", "Ref No", "Buyer's Ref"]
regex = r'\b(?:' + r'|'.join(terms) + r'): (\S+)'
output = re.findall(regex, pg_content)
print(output)  # ['9XD123D', '87CVX61', 'ABC123']
```

Comment: ref_no = re.findall(r"(?:(?<=Buyer's Ref: )|(?<=Ref No: )|(?<=Ref No : ))[\w\d-]+",pg_content) -----> This line is correct. But my requirement is I need to use list ["Buyer's Ref:","Ref No:","Ref No :"] instead to adding "|" inside re.findall()

Comment: I have lot of keyword need to add inside list. I cannot add inside re.findall by putting "|" since the line would be lengthy

Comment: @Ajaydev Check the updated answer if you want to use this approach.  Just build the regex alternation from some input list.

Comment: Is it possible to change this line ref_no = re.findall(r"(?:(?<=Buyer's Ref: )|(?<=Ref No: )|(?<=Ref No : ))[\w\d-]+",pg_content) according to list

Comment: I wouldn't bother with lookbehinds here, given that `re.findall` supports capture groups.  I would use the approach in my answer, in practice.

Comment: My list is in this format  ["Buyer's Ref:","Ref No:","Ref No :"]

Comment: ...and so is mine `:-)`